# ASP.Net Usercontrol Event

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have usercontrol in my page loaded using `Page.Controls.Add(ctrl)`

Now, I have button in that user control and want to fire one function when user clicks on that user control's button.

I have that user control on lots of pages and want to fire different function on that button click of user control.

Comment: C# or VB.NET? Also, do you really need to add it dynamically or can you add it declaratively to the page?

Comment: C#,  yes. I added controls like I said above.   UserControl uc = new UserControl();
                uc = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx");
                dvctrl.Controls.Add(uc);

Comment: But you haven't answered why you think that it must be added dynamically via `LoadControl` since this approach is much more difficult and error-prone(lifecycle issues) than adding it declaratively on the aspx markup. For instance you should add it in Page_Init rather than Page_Load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you should communicate from your `UserControls` to the `Pages` via **Events**. So declare a custom event in the UserControl that'll be raised in the button-click handler and can be handled by the page. On this way every page using this control can react differently.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3